# Cognalys - Android phone - missed call received - number verification failed

Tags: android, android-cognalys

Hi I am using Cognalys for phone number verification.

this is my verification part of the code

```
 private void verify() {


    Cognalys.verifyMobileNumber(Number_verify_Activity.this,
            "REMOVED FOR PRIVACY",
            "REMOVED FOR PRIVACY", etPhoneNo.getText().toString(),
            new VerificationListner() {


                @Override
                public void onVerificationStarted() {


                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationSucess() {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();


                    Toast.makeText(Number_verify_Activity.this, "Your number Verified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Number_verify_Activity.this, NameActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("phonenumber", tvCountryCode + "" + etPhoneNo.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Number_verify_Activity.this, "Your number Not Verified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
```

I have also received missed call from them them but I "it shows Your number Not Verified"

Also I have checked dashboard of Cognalys it shows as the number is verified.

Any ideas?

Thank you!